# Full size for previously uploaded Google+ Instant Upload/Auto Backup photos

Tags: backup, google-plus, google-plus-photos, instant-upload

At some point I changed my Google+ Auto Backup settings to upload photos at full size. I am now switching phones and would like all of the photos on the phone to be backed up to Google+ at full size.  But many of these were backed up earlier when Google+ did not do full size backups.

If I do a manual upload from the Auto Backup settings page, will it reload these previously uploaded files at full size?

Comment: I can't see why not. It will backup whatever is there, you may end up with the full size and the smaller ones. Could you just copy the pics onto SD or your PC, it might just be easier!

Comment: I don't believe it will but I don't know for sure.

Comment: @RossC, the reason I believe it might not is that I assume Auto Backup is smart enough only to incrementally load new pictures, not reload already uploaded ones. So my question comes down to whether Auto Backup will consider these new photos or not.